# Getting the contents of an unknown key

Tags: json, key, jq

I am trying to get the value of the 'url' name which sits underneath a name that I do not know up front. e.g. it's not 'name' or 'size' - just a string that another tool generates - example "x1234" is not known to me by name:

```
"foo": {
  "bar": {
    "x1234": {
      "url": "http://example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

so jq ".foo.bar" returns the "x1234" fragment but what I need is the "url" value underneath it. I've tried many things after reading the docs but I wasn't able to figure out the right syntax.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming `foo` and `bar` are known, you could just do

`.foo.bar[].url`

Let's say if `bar` is also unknown, then do the following

`.foo[][].url`

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use `..`.  For example, provided the input is valid JSON:

```
$ jq '.. | .url? | select(.)' input.json
"http://example.com"
```

Or equivalently (and easier to type):

```
$ jq '.. | .url? // empty' input.json
```

Comment: Thank you - that almost worked.  There are several 'url' fields at various points in that block - I need to return only those that match ".zip". Looks like I can use   | match("zip")  to filter them.

Comment: You may also want to use `endswith(".zip")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which uses **tostream**.  If `filter.jq` contains

```
  tostream
| select(length==2) as [$p,$v]
| if $p[-1] == "url" and ($v|endswith(".zip")) then $v else empty end
```

and if `data.json` contains (note outer { } added to make the example legal JSON and a second entry added to demonstrate excluding values not ending in `.zip` as asked in follow-up comment to [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s answer)

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "x1234": {
        "url": "http://example.com"
      },
      "x1234xxx": {
        "url": "http://example.com/file.zip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then the command

```
jq -M -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
"http://example.com/file.zip"
```